# Angular: How to use Input value from parent component in typescript file

Tags: angular, decorator, angular-components, angular-input

How to use / manipulate `@Input()items` in `child-component.ts` before we pass it to `child-component.html`? I'm getting empty object if console log in `ngOnInit`

**child-component.ts**

```
  @Input()items: any[] = [];
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-component [items]="items"></child-component>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```js
  indexOrders() {
    this.orderService
      .indexOrders()
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
        this.items = res;
        },
        (err) => {
          serviceHttpErrorHandler(err);
        },
      );
  }
```

**sample.json**

> sample response that passed to this.item

```js
[
   {
      "text":"wood",
      "value":"100"
   },
   {
      "text":"chair",
      "value":"200"
   },
   {
      "text":"board",
      "value":"300"
   }
]
```

Comment: `parent.component.html` should be `<child-component [items]="items"></child-component>` with brackets around `items` attribute.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: @JasonWhite, actually it was with bracket in real app. sorry didn't notice when create this question. Do u know how to use `items` in child-component.ts file before pass to html?

Comment: @JasonWhite, No error but Im getting empty object

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the items in the child component before they're rendered in the template?

Comment: Yes correct. If pass directly to template its working but i want to modify before that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `@Input()` on setter methods and not just class member variables.  You add `@Input()` to a method, modify the values and then assign it to a member variable.

#### child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  
  _items: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  @Input()
  public set items(items:any) 
  {
    // YOU CAN MODIFY THE ITEMS HERE
    // BEFORE ASSIGNING TO _items

    this._items = items;
  }

}
```

Below are a stackblitz example along with the angular documentation.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqqn2j
>
> https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: Why people rather do this than doing the modification using the .pipe of RxJS? that way when the subscription happens the data is how you want it.

Comment: @PatricioVargas Using the example of order items, maybe you want to generate a total or subtotals before displaying the data in the child component. You could receive the data through `@Input()` and do the calculations.  If you're just modifying the data structurally then the `pipe` may be a better option.

Comment: You can achieve returning a total of subtotals still with ```pipe()``` RxJS has ```map()```, ```reduce()``` etc that can help you accomplish that.

Answer (score 2):

```
   //Create and Observable
   $items: Observable<any>;

   indexOrders() {
         this.$items= this.orderService
          .indexOrders()
          .pipe(
             //do whatever you want to do here to modify the data,
             catchError(error)
          );
      }
```

**HTML**

```
   <child-component [items]="$items | async"></child-component>
```

The **async** pipe will do the **subcription** and **unsubscription** for you. That way you don't have to destroy the subscription if you use `.subscribe()`

https://blog.angularindepth.com/reading-the-rxjs-6-sources-map-and-pipe-94d51fec71c2

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Take a look to the **async** pipe and the **pipe** from RxJS. People use them all the time in the real world. Angular is all about reactive programming.